# How to copy an entire file from Unix throw Open Text Host Explorer

Tags: unix, mainframe, opentext

I need to get the logs from certain application hosted in Unix. The only tool allow me to see the logs is Open Text Host Explorer version 14. It is my first time using this tool. I can read the logs one by one screen by using PgDown/PgUp and Left/Right command but I didn't find how to get all lines from Open Text Host Explorer and paste in a local txt file. Does someone know how to copy all lines or download the entire file throw Open Test Host Explorer?

Comment: Documentation of the package? Looking at the options on the top bar? FTP?

Comment: I have struggled to find FTP or SFTP options but I didn't. Are you Open Text user? Have you done what I asked in this thread using exactly Open Text? If so, could you write how or maybe add some screen shot.

Comment: No, I'd never heard of the product. Do you have documentation? It seems to be a terminal emulator, so you have a login and you get a prompt from Unix? Why don't you ask the techies at your site what you're supposed to do with it? Do you have a pull-down option for File Transfer or similar? Although it won't be much good if you don't have a login, and if you did you'd have tools. Sorry, that's about as far as I can get.